# Ensure the order of movement of the bird's wing

Tags: java, multithreading

I am trying to modify my code to ensure the order in which the bird's wings fly. If it is displayed to the left, then the bird fly its left wing (should display only left), if to the right, then its right and etc.. For me it is necessary that the launch of 3 threads is saved. By now it displaying in random order. How can I change to make it work?

```
public class Wing implements Runnable {
    private final String name;
    public Wing(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            System.out.println(name);
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CompletableFuture.allOf(
                CompletableFuture.runAsync(new Wing("Flyingleft")),
                CompletableFuture.runAsync(new Wing("Flyingright")),
                CompletableFuture.runAsync(new Wing("Flyingmiddle"))
        ).join();
    }
```

Comment: This is weird.  Why launch multiple threads?  If a specific order is required, the usual solution is to use a single thread;

Comment: This seems like a terrible task to multithread. To get the print statements in order you need to make your threads to communicate (perhaps with `wait()` and `notice()`). Then you have `println()` method - it is synchronized, by multithreading it you don't gain anything (actually you lose some performance by doing so)

Comment: @Amongalen Yes, it is task. I can modify it the way I want

Comment: @markspace You mean to create Thread and then how can I ensure order?

Comment: I'm saying the opposite.  Threads are designed to run asynchronously.  That's how they produce a speed up.  Running threads in a specific order removes the asynchronous aspect and most, if not all, of the speed up.  If you have an actual need to order some result, you'll have to explain better, the solution isn't clear from your question.

Comment: @markspace I mean if first the console displayed "Flyingleft", it should display it everytime, and not to move to another thread, but all thread must run.

Comment: If all you want to do is display text on the console in order, use a single thread.

Comment: @markspace You mean I dont need CompletableFuture.runAsync? Just create a single thread and run?